# Bigquery union/join error

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am getting an error when trying to pull from my google analytics bigquery export tables... I want to look at a month's worth of data with some filters (including one that narrows it down to a list of specific fullvisitorids of interest). However, when I run the following query, I get this error:

Error: (L2:1): JOIN (including semi-join) and UNION ALL (comma) may not be combined in a single SELECT statement. Either move the UNION ALL to an inner query or the JOIN to an outer query.

```
select date, fullvisitorid, visitid, visitstarttime, visitnumber, hits.hitNumber, hits.page.pagePath, hits.page.pageTitle, hits.type --and other columns
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'),TIMESTAMP('2015-02-28')))
where fullvisitorid in (select * from [mydata.visitorid_lookup]) --table includes a list of fullvisitorids I am interested in
and device.browser!='Internet Explorer'
and lower(hits.page.pagePath) not like '%refer%'
and lower(hits.page.pagePath) like '%sample%'
```

So I change my query to this:

```
select * from (
   select date, fullvisitorid, visitid, visitstarttime, visitnumber, hits.hitNumber, hits.page.pagePath, hits.page.pageTitle, hits.type
   FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'),TIMESTAMP('2015-02-28')))
   where device.browser!='Internet Explorer'
   and lower(hits.page.pagePath) not like '%refer%'
   and lower(hits.page.pagePath) like '%sample%')
where fullvisitorid in (select * from [mydata.visitorid_lookup_test])
```

Which then gives me an error saying response is too large to return. It would be cut down significantly if the where statement for fullvisitorid was being executed within the subquery, but of course that doesn't seem possible. So I feel like I'm between a rock and a hard place on this... Is there another way I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "result is too large" error applies to the final result of the query, which means that the result is too large even after semijoin in WHERE is applied. This should work though if you use "Allow Large Results" setting.

Comment: How do I turn that setting on?

Comment: In BigQuery UI, in query editor click on "Show Options", and then check "Allow Large Results" checkbox. If it is greyed out, you need to select name for output table first (this is where the result of the query will be written).

Comment: Wow, a world of new options under the show options... There is a way to preserve the nested structure it looks like. Is there a way I can write to a new table a select * from date ranges where fullvisitorid in my lookup table? Basically I want all the data from about a month's worth, but cut down to just the visitor IDs I'm interested in.

Comment: I am pretty certain it is possible - you can select FlattenResults=false, and you should be able to use SELECT * FROM ... WHERE fullvisitorId IN (SELECT ...) with structure preserved

Comment: @amysong You can save that also as a view, then the query will be shorted if you query and reference the view as a table.

Comment: I am getting back to the original join/union error when I run SELECT * FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'),TIMESTAMP('2015-02-28'))) where fullvisitorid in (SELECT * FROM [mydata.visitorid_lookup_test]). @Pentium10, how do I save results as a view?

Comment: Ahhh this worked! SELECT * FROM (select * from (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'),TIMESTAMP('2015-‌​02-28')))) where fullvisitorid in (SELECT * FROM [mydata.visitorid_lookup_test])